# "Any two codimension-zero balls in a connected manifold are isotopic"

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

This statement was made in Hatcher's notes on 3-manifolds. It is assumed that these balls are smoothly embedded, and the theorem gives a smooth isotopy.

I believe this claim, it seems very clear to me, but how does one go about proving it? By induction? I can prove the statement for smoothly embedded balls in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

I was thinking that *maybe* we could emulate the proof of Alexander's theorem and get a morse function, take regular slices (which would contain balls in the dimension lower, which the inductive hypothesis would isotope to look very nice) but that's as far as I got.

Comment: A proof is given as part of my answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121571/connected-sum-of-topological-manifolds/121635#121635